# Should [p4] be an alias for [perforce]?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

To answer my own question, I'm pretty sure that [p4](/questions/tagged/p4) should be a tag synonym for [perforce](/questions/tagged/perforce) but I figured I'd open it for discussion first.

Currently there are only two questions in the [p4](/questions/tagged/p4) tag without also being tagged [perforce](/questions/tagged/perforce) anyway, and even the tag wiki for [p4](/questions/tagged/p4) refers to the Perforce CLI client.  I can't imagine that there are enough Perforce-CLI specific questions to deserve a separate tag.

[Questions tagged `p4` and not `perforce`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/p4+-perforce)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Merged,

your tags  have been.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**

(no need to add any more text given the info in the question)